# How to select the right-clicked TreeView node in PopupMenu.OnPopup event-handler?

Tags: delphi, vcl, popupmenu, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I have a TreeView (`TTreeView` descendant), where `MultiSelect = False` and `PopupMenu = PopupMenu1`, so when I right-click a node in the TreeView, then `PopupMenu1` is invoked.

In the `PopupMenu1.OnPopup` event-handler, I need the right-clicked node to be programmatically selected. How can I do that?

Example: In the following screenshot, the first node is preselected. When I right-click the last node to invoke the popup menu, then the last node gets VISUALLY selected TOO (although `MultiSelect = False`!):

[image]

However, when I try to detect the selected node in the `PopupMenu1.OnPopup` event-handler:

```
procedure TformMain.PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CodeSite.Send(MyTreeView.Selected.Text', MyTreeView.Selected.Text);
end;
```

... then CodeSite reports still the FIRST node as selected!

So how can I set the right-clicked node in the `PopupMenu1.OnPopup` event-handler to be selected?

(Please note that the TreeView's `OnMouseDown` event-handler gets executed AFTER the `PopupMenu1.OnPopup` event-handler)

Obviously, the `TPopupMenu` class lacks an `OnBeforePopup` event!

Comment: I thought setting the `RightClickSelect` property to `True` would be enough, but sadly no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution I know of is to use the `OnContextPopup` event:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.TreeView1ContextPopup(Sender: TObject; MousePos: TPoint;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  var TreeNode := TreeView1.GetNodeAt(MousePos.X, MousePos.Y);
  if Assigned(TreeNode) then
    TreeNode.Selected := True;
end;
```

Comment: Strangely, the `OnContextPopup` event-handler is never executed. Only the `OnPopup` event-handler gets executed.

Comment: Then you have something strange in your app. Try this in a new VCL app, and you'll see that it works. (Just one of the 1000 possibilities: While troubleshooting, you set the popup menu's `AutoPopup` to `False` and wrote your own code to invoke it in the list-view's `OnMouseDown` handler.)

Comment: I got it working in the `OnMouseDown` event-handler: https://www.screencast.com/t/avv59xeDREq2

Comment: Obviously, the `TRzShellTree` I use or something in my application somehow is blocking the `OnContextPopup` event-handler. Anyway, I got it working in the `OnMouseDown` event-handler. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @user1580348: Yes, `OnMouseDown` works just as well (arguably it is even better -- I think the `OnContextMenu` handles the Menu key (or Shift+F10) correctly, but I haven't verified that).